# How do i remove all space between iframe and div elements?

Tags: html, css, iframe

So i have been trying to remove the space between my div elements and iframe to no success for an hour.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  This is what I have done so far.

css:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.d1 {
    border-style: none;
    background-color: blue;
 }

 iframe {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Here is my html:  I am trying to to remove the white space between the the 2 divs elements on the top and bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- By Christian Soto -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Event Driven JS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="d1">
        <h1>Using JavaScript to Change the HTML</h1>
        </div>
         <iframe id="section">
        <!--    Will be loading different html pages into here  -->
        </iframe>
        <div class="d1">
        <h1>Christian Soto</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could provide a jsfiddle that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the default margin from the `<h1>` tag,
all **[HTML headings](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)** have a default margin style.

```
h1{
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
}
```